# Simulating table Layout in CSS

Tags: css

For all my websites so far I have used table layouts but now I wish to try and use a pure CSS layout. But I am really struggling!

How can I emulate the following in CSS:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Content 1</td>
    <td>Some Content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now lets assume that "Some Content 1" and "Some Content 2" are instead `<img>` tags. Then the resulting output is two images side by side with centred vertical justification. The size of the two cells in the table are the size of the images plus some padding.

So the table is automatically sized to fit the images or whatever content is inside the cells.

But how do I do this in CSS, it is driving me mad! I am nearly at the point of giving up and just using a table layout, and why not, it is so simple.

Any suggestions most gratefully received.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Just wanted to say good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of using "pure CSS". Whats wrong with using tables here? you just need to put the layout of the tables to the css (margin, padding, borders etc).

Comment: I have been trying to do exactly what you want to do, for the past two years. And never succeeded in simulating the table behaviour. If someone could answer this, it would be a "big mystery solved" case!

Comment: http://giveupandusetables.com/

Comment: Adding to Stefan's comment (+1), tableless design means you are not using tables to display data. Using tables to display two images that must be side-by-side is not a problem, it is, indeed, a table. These images must be relevant content and it must be necessary in a semantic way for them to be together. This way you don't attack any "rule" of modern webdesign. If putting them joined is just a matter of aesthetic, you should use CSS (try use a div or a span to each one of the images)

Comment: Correction: "you are note using tables to FORMAT data"

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, just stick to tables. Switch to table-less when CSS will offer all the tools needed for grid-like layouts AND all browser will reliably support them.

Your other choice is juggle a lot of hacks and get a spare F5 key for testing.

Answer (score 3):

> *Then the resulting output is two images side by side with centred vertical justification. The size of the two cells in the table are the size of the images plus some padding.*

Do you mean something like this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2005928</title>
        <style>
            #images img {
                padding: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="images">
            <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width="100" height="50">
            <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" width="50" height="100">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And how do we add another row that aligns and behaves like a table does?

Comment: That's a different question. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Similar layout can be generated using CSS and div tags.

Now a days there many tools available to build such layout using CSS. All modern web page designing tools have these features.

Apart from this tools like Yahoo Grid Builder [(link to Yahoo Grid builder)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) can also be handy for the same.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Firefox(haven't tested in other browsers). The borders are just for illustration.

```
<div>

 <div style="float:left; width:49%;border:1px solid black;">
    <img style="float:right; width:343px" src="http://www.virginia.edu/german/images/Berlin-City2.jpg"/>
 </div>

 <div style="float:right; width:49%;border:1px solid black;">
    <img src="http://www.virginia.edu/german/images/Berlin-City2.jpg"/>
 </div>

</div>
```

Your question is slightly ambiguous (maybe it's me) but you could also mean this:

```
<div>

 <div style="float:left; width:49%; border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="margin:auto; width:343px; border:2px solid red;" >
        <img src="http://www.virginia.edu/german/images/Berlin-City2.jpg"/>
    </div>

 </div>

  <div style="float:left; width:49%; border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="margin:auto; width:343px; border:2px solid red;" >
        <img src="http://www.virginia.edu/german/images/Berlin-City2.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't satisfy all your requirements but is close.

Comment: I don't think the two DIVs will vertically align to the middle as if they were table columns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was under the impression that a floated div must have a fixed width. While browsers support float without a width I don't think it is part of the CSS standard.

Comment: I have corrected my answer to reflect this. Try it again and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `table`, `tr`, and `td` tags to `div`'s and make the 'td-divs' `float:left`. Or, use `display:inline-block` (with all associated problems), or, use `display:table-cell` (with all associated problems).

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the "either or" concept with CSS vs. tables. Both have pros and cons that will drive you up the wall.

I say create as much as you can with CSS, the other layout issues you have, use a table.

Besides, between grid systems and CSS3's TABLE-LAYOUT and template layout module, CSS is really moving towards a "table-based" layout anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see you can do it otherwise is using `<div>` tags and setting their properties, such as float in CSS.

I don't think you can actually create a table in CSS, as CSS defines the style of the page and it's elements, not the elements itself.

Answer (score 0):

To make an element behave like a table using pure CSS, use the `display` property and the values `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, `inline-table`, etc.

This isn't supported by IE, and somewhat defeats the objective of not using tables for columnular layout as the markup is still row based.