# css equivalent of table-row

Tags: css

I am trying to shift my style away from using tables to control formatting, but I haven't seen a simple css solution that does exactly the same thing as

```
<table><tr><td>aribitrary-html-A</td><td>aribitrary-html-B</td></tr><table>
```

All I want is to make sure `aribitrary-html-A` and `aribitrary-html-B` are aligned horizontally.  I have tried various CSS concoctions using `display: inline`, `clear: none`, and `float: left` but they all have unwanted side-effects of moving my content around, while the *table-tr* solution just does what I want, regardless of what's in the arbitrary HTML, and regardless of what is in HTML that contains my table.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How **exactly** are you floating and clearing floats?

Comment: I don't exactly remember all the wrong things I tried... my question is: what is a solution that *works*?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005928/simulating-table-layout-in-css

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a grid system then like [960gs](http://960.gs/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        content 1
    </div>
</div>


#wrap {
    width: 50%; /* change this as you wish */
}

#left, #right {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Change the first CSS selector to `#wrap div`

Answer (score 0):

Just create two Divs and align the one you want to have on the left side.

Like so (update):

```
<div id="wrap" style="  width:300px; 
                          margin:auto;                      
                        border: 1px solid black; 
                        padding:1px">
    <div id ="A" style="float:left; 
                        border: 1px solid black;"> aribitrary-html-A </div>

    <div id = "B" style="border: 1px solid black;"> aribitrary-html-A</div>
</div>
```

Update: I added a wrapper with a defined width. Also I used some borders to visualize the table-like layout. Hope that helps.

Comment: that has a side effect of moving everything to the left

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<div>`s and decent CSS. For people that aren't confident enough (or lazy, like me) Yahoos [YUI CSS Grid Builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) is invaluable! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you?

```
    <div style="width:400px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="background-color:red;float:left;height:200px;width:200px;">

        </div>
        <div style="background-color:blue;float:right;height:200px;width:200px;">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Just don't put your css within style attributes like I did.

Comment: that creates unwanted empty space between the 2 div's

Answer (score 0):

Wrap element in a div, set fixed width for the wrapper. Give each element in the div a width and set the margin to 0 auto.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the CSS "float" property to left on every element you want to display horizontally, and make sure each of those elements have a set width.